# php.ini file setting being ignored - tring to change upload_max_filesize

Tags: php, debian, apache-2.4, php-fpm

Running php8.2 with fpm - I have rebooted server, I have restarted both php8.2-fpm and apache2. I am 100% certain I've changed the correct php.ini file - infact I have changed all 3, apache2, cli and fpm. I have also tried to disable fpm and enable apache2 php - same result except it's reads the /etc/php/8.2/apache2/php.ini

[image]

[image]

[image]